# why fullscreen functionality is not working in chrome?

Tags: javascript

I need to open the window in fullscreen using javascript. I suceeded in mozilla. but in google chrome its not working. Why is it so.? anybody help me.
I use this javascript for mozzilla.

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Progress window!" onClick="window.open('divs.htm','mywindow',
'fullscreen=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no')">
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

> **`fullscreen`**
>
> Do not use. Not implemented in Mozilla. There are no plans to implement this feature in Mozilla.
>
> This feature no longer works in MSIE 6 SP2 the way it worked in MSIE 5.x. The Windows taskbar, as well as the titlebar and the status bar of the window are not visible, nor accessible when fullscreen is enabled in MSIE 5.x.
>
> `fullscreen` always upsets users with large monitor screen or with dual monitor screen. Forcing fullscreen onto other users is also extremely unpopular and is considered an outright rude attempt to impose web author's viewing preferences onto users.
>
> Supported in: IE
>
> `fullscreen` does not really work in MSIE 6 SP2.

Comment: So,Is there any other way to open the window in chrome in full screen..?

Comment: @priya Apart from using a plugin like Flash, I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the fullscreen attribute is not cross browser compatible. It's called Kiosk mode i believe and chrome does not support it and so do many other browsers.

Comment: So,Is there any other way to open the window in chrome in full screen..?