# Opening a JS popup window in chrome browser, the window size is too small?

Tags: javascript

I write a script to open a popup window, the window is too small in chrome browser compared with Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Here is my script,

```
function openPopup(sId,tId)
{
    window.open ("index.php?sid=" + sid+"&tid="+tid, "test", "fullscreen,scrollbars,hotkeys=no");
}
```

Any help? thanks for advance.

Comment: Which verson of chrome are u using?

Comment: this is my chrome version 25.0.1364.97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fixed `width` and `height` in your Popup window

```
window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!, i go for fixed width & height.
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003174/why-fullscreen-functionality-is-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height when calling the window.open(). Check [this post](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, fullscreen is not a parameter for window options. 
try height and width attributes to set the size